# Quarkus: Find and invoke annotated methods for listener

Tags: events, reflection, quarkus

I want to create a custom event framework that processes the events received via Kafka and executes the corresponding event listeners.

The event listeners are methods that are annotated with an @EventListener annotation.

So if my application has received a Kafka message in the background, it searches for all associated listeners and calls the methods.

If possible (for speed optimization), all listener methods should be searched for and saved in a map when the program starts.

Spring could go through all beans and determine the corresponding methods via reflection. Under Quarkus, however, this is not available to me or should not be used.

So how do I solve this problem under Quarkus?

Comment: In Quarkus, you would do this during application build in a Quarkus extension. You can start here: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions

Comment: What about interceptors and CDI events?